# Does a long lived Linq2Sql DataContext ever remove references to tracked objects?

Tags: linq-to-sql

We have inherited some code that makes use of Linq2Sql and we've just found that an instance of the Data Context is being stored in a class member that is defined as private.  As this class is used inside a web application once the class is created, an instance of the data context will be created and assigned to the static member - resulting in an instance of the data context that will now be used by all instances of that class (so across all users, a potential problem in itself) but also that instance of the data context will now exist for the duration of the web application (as it is held in a static class member).

Ignoring the bad design decisions that were originally taken, my question here is what happens to the data read into the data context?  I know the session in NHibernate keeps a reference to any objects it reads / creates so it can track changes, etc. and the session can slowly grow and grow and never clears out unless you implicitly tell it to.  Does Linq2Sql do something similar, so if the web application lived for ever (without recycling) would this linq2Sql context slowly grow until the machine either ran out of memory, or potentially it has read the entire database by satisfying the incoming requests?  It's my understanding that a context isn't usually like a cache, which will remove items that "expire" from itself, or when hitting a memory limit, start removing least used items.   Because of what it does, I don't think the data context is ever able to do that?  Has anyone had experience of this, and either confirm my understanding or provide a reference to show what a long lived data context can do to stop this happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the `DataContext` will keep track of objects it has read if its `ObjectTrackingEnabled` property is set to `true`. It is enabled by default. You cannot change the value of `ObjectTrackingEnabled` to false if the `DataContext` is already tracking state.

We set `ObjectTrackingEnabled` to false when we are just doing reads with no intention of making any changes. You cannot call `SubmitChanges` when `ObjectTrackingEnabled` is set to false.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a `DataContext` will retain references to all of the objects that have ever been associated with it. It *might* be that objects that have been deleted will be expelled from the cache, but otherwise it holds on to them, no matter how much memory it will cost.

Depending on the architecture and the size of the data set, the worker process will, at some point, run out of memory and crash. The only remedy would be to disable object tracking (through `ObjectTrackingEnabled`) or to refactor the code so it either uses a single `DataContext` per request, or (and this is not recommended) to regularly recycle the application-wide `DataContext`.